# UIBarButtonItem set tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have one question about bar button item, and my problem is I create 4 buttons of bar button item but I can't set the tag for them. Here is my code:

```
 for(int i=0;i<numeroDeSubMenus;i++){

    //Create the button
    barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setUrl)];
    barButtonItem.image = [self imageWithImage:imageSubMenu scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
    // button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    // [button setImage:imageSubMenu forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    for (NSString *titulos in arrayNomesSubMenu) {

        barButtonItem.title = titulos;
    }

    // barButtonItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    //                 initWithCustomView:button];

    // barButtonItem.image = [self imageWithImage:imageSubMenu scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
    NSLog(@"%@",[barButtonItem description]);
    [numberofbuttons addObject:barButtonItem];

}
for (int tag = 0; tag < numeroDeSubMenus; tag ++) {
    [barButtonItem setTag:tag];
}

[toolBar setItems:numberofbuttons];
// toolBar.items = numberofbuttons;
toolBar.translucent = NO;
```

numeroDeSubMenus = 4 (buttons)

When I run this, it shows me the 4 buttons, but the tag is the same, and it is the last number (3). How can I put a tag for each button?

This is the action of button, that says where to go and each button I click.

```
- (void)setUrl
{
    if (barButtonItem.tag == 0) {

        NSLog(@"1ºbutao");
    }
    if (barButtonItem.tag == 1) {

        NSLog(@"2ºbutao");
    }
    if (barButtonItem.tag == 2) {

        NSLog(@"3ºbutao");
    }
    if (barButtonItem.tag == 3) {

        NSLog(@"4ºbutao");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the tag to the same button instance every time. Try this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<numeroDeSubMenus;i++){

    //Create the button
    barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setUrl:)];
    [barButtonItem setTag:i];
    barButtonItem.image = [self imageWithImage:imageSubMenu scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
   // button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //[button setImage:imageSubMenu forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    for (NSString *titulos in arrayNomesSubMenu) {

        barButtonItem.title = titulos;

    }

   // barButtonItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
              //      initWithCustomView:button];

  //  barButtonItem.image = [self imageWithImage:imageSubMenu scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
    NSLog(@"%@",[barButtonItem description]);
    [numberofbuttons addObject:barButtonItem];
}



[toolBar setItems:numberofbuttons];
//toolBar.items = numberofbuttons;
toolBar.translucent = NO;
```

Ok change your method that receives the click action to this:

```
- (IBAction)setUrl:(UIBarButtonItem *)button {
    NSLog(@"%i", button.tag);
}
```

Im guessing you have a instance variable `barButtonItem` and that one will only hold the last reference since thats the one you assign to it in your loop. The other buttons are just in your array and in the actual navigation bar.

Comment: hi , thanks for answer , but already try that and still the same. i forgott to show the method for action : - (void)setUrl
{
    if (barButtonItem.tag == 0) {
        
        NSLog(@"1ºbutao");
        
    }
    if (barButtonItem.tag == 1) {
        
        NSLog(@"2ºbutao");
        
    }
    if (barButtonItem.tag == 2) {
        
        NSLog(@"3ºbutao");
        
    }
    if (barButtonItem.tag == 3) {
        
        NSLog(@"4ºbutao");
        
    }

} and when i press the button, its says the same , "button nº4" that s my log

Comment: Try this. Note that I also added a ":" to the selector in the initialisation of the button.

Comment: hi mate , thanks for the help already fix the problem . and i shared the code if someone have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

No need of 2 for loops. Your some code is wrong.

```
for(int i=0;i<numeroDeSubMenus;i++){

    //Create the button
    barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setUrl)];
    barButtonItem.image = [self imageWithImage:imageSubMenu scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
    // button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //[button setImage:imageSubMenu forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    for (NSString *titulos in arrayNomesSubMenu) {

        barButtonItem.title = titulos;

    }

   // barButtonItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
          //      initWithCustomView:button];

  //  barButtonItem.image = [self imageWithImage:imageSubMenu scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
    [barButtonItem setTag:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",[barButtonItem description]);
    [numberofbuttons addObject:barButtonItem];

}
```

Comment: already try that , that s why i put separate , and still gave me the same think , all buttons get the same tag

Comment: already edit my topic , i put the method of action each button , and when i run the app , when i click the buttons it says "4ºbuttao" its mean 4ºbutton

Answer (score 0):

I have already fixed the problem, as you can see in the code, the method of action:

```
- (void)setUrl
```

I must replace with:

```
- (void)setUrl:(UIBarButtonItem*) sender
```

and change on all if statements for this:

```
if (sender.tag == 0) {
```

...

and when I create the button

```
        barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setUrl:)];
```

I must change: `action:@selector(setUrl:)`

Thanks.